# Are water and gasses 'objects', for the purposes of Leomund's Tiny Hut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

In the spell description of Leomund's Tiny Hut it says:

> All other creatures and objects are barred from passing through it.

What counts as an object? Because isn't everything technically an object according to the laws of physics? So wouldn't that mean that water and gasses can't enter it, correct? Or some sort of weather implement?

Comment: What's a “weather implement”?

Comment: natural forces such as rain, floods, high winds, storms, tornadoes. etc.

Answer (score 0):

But you don't play RPG according to the laws of physics: you play them according to your imagination guided by the rules.

In D&D 5e, a creature is anything with a stat block an an object is every other material thing. Liquids and gasses are objects, water and air elementals are creatures: both are banned.

Comment: so for example rain can't get through the spell?

Comment: Actually, this just came up in a game we were playing.  It says it makes "The atmosphere inside the space is
comfortable and dry, regardless of the weather outside."  Another question mentions hemisphere's have a bottom.  So can this be cast under water? Or even for safety on the plane of fire or vacuum?

Comment: In 5E, the spell says "dome", not "hemisphere".